# Extended zone URL in Alert emails

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint web application with a default zone (window auth only) with a url `http://internal.companysite.com` and an extended zone (FBA only) with a url `http://external.companysite.com`. The later one is a public url for non-employees.
When a external user (non-employee) subscribes for alerts, he/she gets the alert emails with internal urls (except for 'Mobile View' link). However the very first subscription confirmation email has proper internal urls embeded in it.

I have seen a couple of discussions on *MSDN* forums but none of them provide a useful suggestion.

[MSDN - SharePoint Foundation 2013 AAM, alerts, URL in email alert](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a1fafda5-60d9-4a87-a50a-e3ad5c268e73/sharepoint-foundation-2013-aam-alerts-url-in-email-alerts?forum=sharepointadmin)

[Alerts in Extended Web Application](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/73510952-3f63-4750-b28a-148af9602063/alerts-in-extended-web-application?forum=sharepointgeneral)

I have seen few posts talking about changing default zone but in my case it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is by design, Alerts always use the default zone URL. In your case you have two zones, so what you are seeing it is expecting.

the solution you mentioned is the solution either customized it or enable both authentication in same zone( default).

[Check this coding solution.](https://timpanariuovidiu.wordpress.com/2014/06/23/sharepoint-2013-alerts/)